# Attribute Routing difference?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

What is the difference between the following?

```
[Route("movies/genre/{genre}")]
public ActionResult ViewByGenre(string genre="action")
```

Instead of

```
[Route("movies/genre/{genre=action}")]
public ActionResult ViewByGenre(string genre)
```

Comment: Why not try and see ? What problem do you have with using it in the one of the ways ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in this statment

```
[Route("movies/genre/{genre}")]
public ActionResult ViewByGenre(string genre="action")
```

`genre` parameter isn't optional in the route, only `ViewByGenre` function will valorize it.

here

```
[Route("movies/genre/{genre=action}")]
public ActionResult ViewByGenre(string genre)
```

you are saying that `genre` parameter is optional in the route. If it arrives null it will take `action` value. ViewByGenre function always should have genre parameter valorized

refer [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) for documentation

In this way you are doing attribute routing. The advantages are that Attribute Routing gives you more control over the URI in the applications, when you edit something in the code it won't break another route. 
On the other side an example of Convention base rules is when you decide your rules in the RouteConfig.cs file like this

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: Okay, I get this. I have few other questions as well.

Comment: if you need help I'm here

Comment: Well what is the main difference between `Attribute Routing` and Convention-based routing? Which one should I go for?

Comment: I've updated my answer, hope it is clear, if you have any doubt let me know